# Is it better to break up a VERY long MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, performance

I end up having a very huge query similar to this:

```
 DELETE FROM compilation WHERE id = 1574 OR id = 1573 OR id = 1571 OR id = 1572 OR id = 1570 OR id = 1569 OR id = 1568 OR id = 1567 OR id = 1566 OR id = 1565 OR id = 1564 OR id = 1563 OR id = 1562 OR id = 1560 OR id = 1561 OR id = 1558 OR id = 1559 OR id = 1557 OR id = 1556 OR id = 1555 OR id = 1554
```

But I have recently discovered that I have over 2746 "OR" statements. Is this a bad practice? Should I do a foreach loop and delete one record per connection?

Also is there a character limit per query in MySQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, the fewer round trips to the mysql server (apache?) the better. 1 is good. If there's a limit, I've never heard of anyone hitting it.

Answer (score 11):

Use `IN()`

```
DELETE FROM compilation 
WHERE id IN (1574,1573,1571)
```

or if you have a sequence of numbers you want to delete use `BETWEEN`

```
DELETE FROM compilation 
WHERE id BETWEEN 1571 AND 1574
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2746 "OR" statements, you might want to consider putting the ID's to a temporary table and then use the table in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off executing the delete as one statement in MySQL rather than having multiple round-trips to the application, because the handshake between the application and the server takes much more time than a single statement deleting many rows.

However, looking at your statement it's clear that you could summarize it as:

```
 DELETE FROM compilation WHERE id BETWEEN 1554 AND 1574;
```

If you can find a way to get the application to identify it as a range rather than a set of distinct values, you'll have a much easier time.

Comment: I can't use BETWEEN because I may have records in between that don't need deleting. Maybe I gave a bad example, as it didn't reflect that condition.